# Why vim returns E488: Trailling characters to my function?

Tags: vim, neovim

I am trying to execute a yapf command to format my python file when I save it, so I created a function to call this command:

```
function Format_python_file()
    silent :!yapf --style="{based_on_style: pep8, indent_width: 4}" -i %
    silent :e %
endfunction

autocmd BufWritePost *.py call Format_python_file() <afile>
```

Comment: it certainly seems like you could figure out which line in your function is causing this command. Have you tried that?

Comment: I think that is the first line, that runs the yapf command, but i don't know how to fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with your `autocmd` line, you have a trailing `<afile>` there.

In fact, the message I see is quite explicit about that:

```
Error detected while processing BufWritePost Autocommands for "*.py":
E488: Trailing characters: <afile>
```

You should just drop the `<afile>`, the function itself already works on the current buffer, doesn't need any argument or other reference to the current file.

---

Also note that it's a good practice to put your `autocmd`s inside an `augroup` which gets cleared first. That way, if you reload your source file (vimrc or otherwise), it won't create duplicated `autocmd`s.

The cleaner way to set up this `autocmd` would be:

```
augroup python_yapf
    autocmd!
    autocmd BufWritePost *.py call Format_python_file()
augroup END
```

Comment: It works, but if I save the file and exit vim with :x or ZZ, why it doesn't works?

Comment: Does it work if you use `<afile>` in your yapf command? As in: `silent :!yapf --style="{based_on_style: pep8, indent_width: 4}" -i <afile>`